# Running CompletableFuture.thenAccept from the calling thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I want to call `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` to delegate a blocking task to another thread. Once that task completes I would like for the `CompletableFuture.thenAccept` consumer to run in the context of the calling thread.

For example:

```
// Thread 1

CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
   // Thread 2

   return BlockingMethod();
}).thenAccept((
   Object r) -> {

   // Thread 1
});
```

The following code suggests that `CompletableFuture.thenAccept` runs in its own thread; probably the same pool as `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` as I get the same thread ID when I run it:

```
System.out.println("Sync thread supply " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {

   System.out.println("Async thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

   try {
      Thread.sleep(2000);
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return true;
}).thenAccept((
   Boolean r) -> {

   System.out.println("Sync thread consume " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
});

Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Is it possible to have `CompletableFuture.thenAccept` run concurrently with the calling thread?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `CompletableFuture` will only execute the `Consumer` you register with `thenAccept` when the receiver `CompletableFuture` (one returned by `supplyAsync`) is completed, since it needs the value it was completed with.

If the receiver `CompletableFuture` is complete when `thenAccept` is invoked, then the `Consumer` will be executed in the calling thread. Otherwise, it will execute on whatever thread completes the `Supplier` submitted to `supplyAsync`.

> Is it possible to have `CompletableFuture.thenAccept` run concurrently
>   with the calling thread?

This is a confusing question because a thread can only run one thing at a time. There's no *concurrently* for a single thread. *Concurrently* is a property that spans multiple threads.

If you want the `Consumer` to run on the same thread that invoked `thenAccept`, then `join` on the `CompletableFuture`, blocking this thread until the future is completed. You can then execute the `Consumer` yourself or call `thenAccept` to execute it for you.

For example

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> receiver = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    System.out.println("Async thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
});

receiver.join();
Consumer<Boolean> consumer = (Boolean r) -> {
    System.out.println("Sync thread consume " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
};

consumer.accept(receiver.get());
```

(Exception handling omitted.)

---

If you want the `Consumer` to run in parallel with the `Supplier` supplied to `supplyAsync`, that's not possible. That `Consumer` is meant to consume the value produced by the `Supplier`. That value isn't available until the `Supplier` is finished.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your idea right that you want to fork I/O-intensive tasks but do all processing in the "event loop" (think Javascript), then your code could be translated to

```
Executor eventLoop = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Executor ioMultiplexor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

eventLoop.execute(() -> {
    System.out.println("event loop thread supply " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("I/O multiplexor thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }, ioMultiplexor).thenAcceptAsync((Boolean r) -> {
        System.out.println("event loop thread consume " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }, eventLoop);
});

Thread.sleep(3000);
// shut down executors
```

This prints

```
event loop thread supply 10
I/O multiplexor thread 11
event loop thread consume 10
```

If this code is used for some request handling where there can be many concurrent requests, you would probably want to have one global `eventLoop` and one global `ioMultiplexer`, and you would also want to release the main request handling thread once it finishes submitting the task onto `eventLoop`.